# Asymptotic Expansion for a Function involving a Weird Integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, power-series, divergent-series, laurent-series

So I'm trying to find the asymptotic expansion as $x \to \infty$ of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\bigg[A-\int \frac{\lambda^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}dx\bigg]^\frac{1}{\alpha}}$$

Note that $\lambda>0$ and $\alpha>0$. We can also see that $x \to \infty$ means that we can basically treat A as some arbitrary constant of integration and ignore the constant factor that comes out of the integral, but I have no clue on where to go from here. I'm basically stuck. Note here that $f(x) \to \infty$ is a constraint as well.

Comment: Your question is ill-posed. You can't use $x$ as both the argument of a function $f(x)$ *and* a dummy integration variable.

Comment: It's an indefinite integral. It has to be a function of x. You can rewrite the integral in the question as $$\int_{x_0}^x \frac{\lambda^y}{\Gamma(y+1)}dy$$ where $x_0>0$ fixed.

Comment: it's not 'if I want'. The way you wrote the question is meaningless. And it is *not* equivalent to what you wrote in your comment, which instead makes perfect sense. Please edit your question.

Comment: How is my question unclear? An indefinite integral of a function of x has to be a function of x. It's not unclear at all. If I'm looking for an asymptotic expansion as a function of x with an indefinite integral that's a function of x, the question is obviously well-defined. What I wrote there is just another way of defining what amounts to the same thing.

Comment: That's particularly true because A is arbitrary, which means you have a constant of integration that fits right into the outer part of the integral. So both ways of defining the integral must necessarily be equivalent.

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo why don't you try to answer instead of putting dots over the is?? Obsolete comments are flagged.

Comment: I put it on here because I'm stuck. I don't want this to turn into mudslinging on both sides. I apologize if I did something that may have been inflammatory in any way. I'd like to keep this civil and if this veers away from being civil, I'll delete the question and ask it again. I'm sorry if I did something considered out of line. I don't know the rules and I'm sorry if I broke them. I really like Stack Exchange and I'd rather not be flagged.